# Unlink computer from an Xmarks group

Tags: bookmarks, xmarks

I have Xmarks setup to synchronize bookmarks across several machines using Firefox exclusively. I decommissioned one machine, completely uninstalling Firefox. On the remaining machines in the Xmarks group, I can invoke `Xmarks >> Open Remote Tabs` and I see that the decommissioned machine is still showing up with what it last reported. I find no page (akin to Dropbox's list of linked machines) where I can disconnect or unlink this decommissioned machine. I really dislike leaving any such detritus out there, with even the remotest possibility that that machine could later be used to review all my bookmarks.  How can I unlink the machine completely? Xmark's own help site offered only one suggestion, to change the password, which would not remove the machine from showing up under "Open Remote Tabs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in Xmarks FAQ collection under [How do I clear old unwanted tabs?](https://buy.xmarks.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=3133) Quoting verbatim:

1. Go to my.xmarks.com.
2. Select "Tools".
3. Select "Open Remote Tabs".
4. Click "Clear Data".
5. The list that appears shows each browser for which Xmarks has open tabs. Select the browsers whose data you wish to remove from the Xmarks servers by checking the box to the left.
6. Click "Delete".